# Множественное число разносклоняемых существительных на -мя

Tags: морфология

Лишь 4 (бремя, вымя, пламя, темя) из 10 разносклоняемых сущ-ых (на -мя) употребляются только в единственном числе?

Но, что странно, прогуглив, я нашел мн. ч. слова "вымя" - выменА. А в учебнике пишется, что оно ТОЛЬКО в ед. ч. Как быть теперь??

Множественное число некоторых из них я знаю:

- Время - Времена
- Имя - Имена
- Семя - Семена
  Знамя - Знамена
  Племя - Племена
  Знамя - Знамёна

И еще. Звучит как-то незнакомо "стремя - стремена". Вы могли бы привести пример на "стремена" в предложении? Спасибо!

Comment: Читайте, *roger*, больше - это самый лучший способ узнать язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конный спорт - это, конечно, уникальный вид спорта, но он никуда не исчез, и слово СТРЕМЕНА употребляется довольно часто, вот, например: http://www.equitaly.com/ru/Наши стремена GREEP - это самая комфортная и незаменимая модель стремян из существующих на рынке.
Платформа сконструирована таким образом, чтобы гарантировать максимальную опору и оптимальную устойчивость ноги благодаря своим «увеличенным» по сравнению с обычными стременами размерам и эффективной системе антискольжения.

А вот в объявлениях: "Продам редингот,сапоги 38р-р, безопасные стремена";

Вот ещё: "Модель FLY была задумана и сконструирована для всех наездников и наездниц, которые хотят иметь легкие стремена, но с оптимальной прочной опорой. 
Материал, из которого изготовлены стремена FLY, – это сплав алюминия с магнием, который позволяет сделать их легкими, но в то же время очень прочными".

Мало того, стремена есть в снаряжении альпинистов; в ортопедии применяются тоже стремена:
"Стремена Павлика – это самое щадящее для суставов и самое удобное для малыша ортопедическое приспособление".

Answer (score 1):

> Лишь 4 (бремя, вымя, пламя, темя) из 10 разносклоняемых сущ-ых (на -мя) употребляются только в единственном числе?

По большому счету только первое из них следует считать не имеющим множественного числа в силу общих законов: отвлеченные (и смежные с ними) существительные регулярно не имеют множественного числа, хотя это тоже не абсолютный закон. 
Что же касается остальных, то, пожалуй, в духе Зализняка следует их множественное число считать существующим (ибо само понятие вполне возможно) но неупотребительным. Поэтому, я допускаю окказиональное использование форм "темена", "вымена" и даже "пламена", что вы и могли обнаружить с помощью гугла. Нормативной такую форму признать, естественно, нельзя.

Про стремена уже сказали. Возможно вы подсознательно как-то ассоциировали "стремена" со сленговым "стрёмно" - отсюда и ощущение чего-то неправильного.

Answer (score 0):

Пример из словаря Ожегова: "Вдеть ноги в стремена"